# Reference to variable in any component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, reference

I am working in Unity. I have a script that will output a nice sine wave to a float and I want to use it with floats in different components. For example, I want to modify the volume of an AudioSource component and the intensity of a Light2D. The problem is that I want to be able to affect any float in any script, I shouldn’t need to hard code each individual float. For example, instead of typing audioSource.volume into the program I want to be able to assign a float reference in the editor. Is this possible?

PS: This is my first post and I hope it is easy to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible directly since `float` is a **value** type, not a reference!

Also unless all your target scripts share a common interface/parent class you can't just let **any** component react to the change.

---

You could/should use inheritance and have a base class like

```
public abstract class SinusWave : MonoBehaviour
{
    // However your implementation looks like so far e.g.
    
    [SerializeField] float amplitude = 1;
    [SerializeField] float amplitudeOffset = 0;
    [SerializeField] float frequency = 1;

    private readonly float twoPI = 2 * Mathf.PI;

    private void Update()
    {
        var value = amplitudeOffset + Mathf.Sin(twoPI * Time.time * frequency) * amplitude;
        OnNewValue(value);
    }

    // Call this method whenever changing your float value
    protected abstract void OnNewValue(float newValue);
}
```

And then you can implement specific components according to your needs

```
[RequireComponent (typeof(AudioSource))]
public class AudioSourceVolumeSinusWave : SinusWave
{
    [SerializeField] AudioSource audioSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!audioSource) audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    protected override void OnNewValue (float newValue)
    {
        audioSource.volume = newValue;
    }
}
```

Or

```
[RequireComponent (typeof (Light))]
public class LightIntensitySinusWave : SinusWave
{
    [SerializeField] Light light;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!light) light = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    protected override void OnNewValue (float newValue)
    {
        light.intensity = newValue;
    }
}
```

---

Or if you want one central sinus wave component but different listeners you can basically do the same but with a different parent class like

```
public class SinusWave : MonoBehaviour
{
    // However your implementation looks like so far e.g.

    [SerializeField] float amplitude = 1;
    [SerializeField] float amplitudeOffset = 0;
    [SerializeField] float frequency = 1;

    private readonly float twoPI = 2 * Mathf.PI;

    private void Update()
    {
        var value = amplitudeOffset + Mathf.Sin(twoPI * Time.time * frequency) * amplitude;
        
        // Inform all active receivers
        foreach(var receiver in SinusWaveReceiver.instances)
        {
            receiver.OnNewValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And then rather have a parent class like

```
public abstract class SinusWaveReceiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static readonly HashSet<SinusWaveReceiver> _instances = new HashSet<SinusWaveReceiver>();
    public static HashSet<SinusWaveReceiver> instances => new HashSet<SinusWaveReceiver>(_instances);

    protected virtual void Awake ()
    {
        _instances.Add(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy ()
    {
        _instances.Remove(this);
    }

    protected abstract void OnNewValue (float newValue);
}
```

And then just inherit your specific implementations from that one instead

```
public class LightIntensitySinusWave : SinusWaveReceiver { ... }

public class AudioSourceVolumeSinusWave : SinusWaveReceiver { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I assumed I would have to do.